# Keep colours the same between facetted plots / subplots

Tags: r, plotly, legend, subplot

Following the [R plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/r/subplot.html), facetting happens by splitting a dataset on 1 variable, and then applying the same plot function on each split, and finally combining the plots using `subplot`.

If I facet a dataframe on 1 variable, but color on another, I might end up having a different subset of variables to color by in each subplot, causing the same value to have different colors between subplot.

```r
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
iris%>%
  mutate(name = unlist(c(rep(c("A", "B"), 30), rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 30)))) %>% 
  group_by(Sepal.Length > 5) %>%
  do(p=plot_ly(., x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, color = ~name, type = "scatter")) %>%
  subplot(nrows = 1, shareX = TRUE, shareY = TRUE)
```

[image]

On the left subplot, datapoints with the name "B" are colored blue, while on the right subplot, they are colored red.

**How can I ensure that the colors are stable across Subplots?**

Keeping duplicates out of the legend would also be a plus!

Comment: Are the colors based on factors?

Comment: They are based on strings. If converting to factors can solve the problem, I am very interested in seeing that as a solution.

Comment: If you change the `mutate`  statement like: `mutate(name = factor(unlist(c(rep(c("A", "B"), 30), rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 30))))) ` this returns the same colour because plotly is colouring based on the same level. But, the legend still showing two 'B' values. I'm not more experienced in plotly to fix that

Comment: Why do you need `group_by(Sepal.Length > 5)`? Does it accomplish something? If not, just remove it, and you should be fine even without converting `name` to factor class (and it will remove duplicates from the legend)

Comment: @Darmist it accomplishes nothing except forcing a split into two facets, where one facet only has data points named `A` and `B` and the other facet has `A`, `B` and `C` and thus showing how the colors changes between similarly named data points between two subplots.

Comment: @Olsgaard Okay, I see now, and they are duplicated because of these 2 groups... Well, I am not very familiar with `plotly`, but can offer a `ggplot2` solution if you are interested in it

Comment: @RobertoT, if you want an accepted answer, please feel free to post your comment as an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have your names as `factor` and only show the legend for one of the
subplots.

<sub>Here, I am setting `showlegend` to `Sepal.Length > 5` because that group has all the names/levels. If you have cases where no single group covers all the names, then we need to do a little more data preparation beforehand.</sub>

```r
iris %>%
  mutate(name = factor(unlist(c(rep(c("A", "B"), 30), 
                                rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 30))))) %>% 
  group_by(Sepal.Length > 5) %>%
  do(p=plot_ly(., x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, 
               color = ~name, type = "scatter", mode = "markers",
               showlegend = ~unique(Sepal.Length > 5))) %>%
  subplot(nrows = 1, shareX = TRUE, shareY = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>